# The Capacitive Sensor library on a D1 Mini

Tags: esp8266, sensors, pins, esp32

I want to set up a hand-made capacitive sensor on a D1 Mini, as in [this tutorial](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/CapacitiveSensor?from=Main.CapSense), so that I can get specific capacitive readings. But I couldn't get the CapacitiveSensor library to work with the D1 Mini. Just to make sure I wasn't crazy, I fired up an Arduino Nano knockoff, and the library worked just fine.

I found [a thread from early 2017](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=462160.0) on this topic, which had various suggestions, none of which worked.

Does anyone know either how to make this library work with a D1 Mini, or another efficient way of getting capacitive readings on digital pins on a D1 Mini?

Comment: which pins are you using?

Comment: I've tried every combo I could think of. I know to avoid D0 / D3 / D4 / D8 (but tried them anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it looks like the answer was in [the early 2017 thread](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=462160.0) all along. I switched to a 400k resistor and it works! (I've only verified this just for pins 5 -> 6, although I'd expect it works for any combination of pins not including D0 / D3 / D4 / D8.)

However, a caveat here -- *it doesn't work well.* With an Arduino and a ~6m resistor, you can sense a change in capacitance from several inches away, with a nice continuous increase in capacitance as you get closer. At least for me, the 400k resistor had very low operational range, only maybe 1/2 in. or so, and even then the differences were subtle. But increasing to a 600k resistor replicated the initial problem -- I just got the "-2" error message consistently. And going down to a 200k resistor just decreased the range as you'd expect. So there seems to be a very narrow operational range of resistance for the D1 Mini, with less utility than the Arduino.